# can not access recovery on htc one m8

Tags: htc-one

What I basically need: I want to access recovery(or bootloader, I am not sure what its really called) to do a factory reset.

History of the problem: My little sister entered the pattern incorrectly too many times and now the phone is locked asking for gmail and password. Although I know it, but the phones wifi is disabled, so it says "wrong username or password" and hence I can not unlock it. I want to do a factory reset via the recovery but the phone is not going into it even though I press volume down + power(I also tried the volume up).
USB debugging is off, and the device is not rooted...
please help me, how can I get around this damn problem?

Comment: Where do you end up when holding volume down + (briefly) power button?

Comment: the phone boots normaly, it ends up at the lock screen

Comment: Your volume down button might be broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your volume down button isn't broken, may be the "fast boot" feature is activated in the settings (not to be confused with fastboot) that can prevent the phone from booting in the HBoot. 
Try this:

- From the lock screen, press the power button
- Then select reboot or restart. The phone will reboot
- Hold volume down button before the phone power itself on.
- You should be in the HBoot Menu (3 android guys)
- From the just select Clear data

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. That was the case precisely. I had to restart so that it could go in. Not shut it down

Comment: Yeah, I owe you that. I did press the upward arrow head, but it doesnt let me vote. It tells me I dont have the reputation..